# Que pasa si no coloco el aviso de las cookies en mi sitio web?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, navegador-web

Tengo una web que utiliza un csrftoken pero en mi web no le aviso al usuario que se estan usando cookies, que problemas puede traer esto?

pasa es que estoy teniendo inconvenientes con mi pagina porque algunos navegadores no están guardando el token en las cookies, por eso me preguntaba si era por el aviso o no se que está pasando.

en el navegador chrome funciona perfectamente, pero en otros navegadores no funciona, intente cambiar la configuracion en firefox permitiendo todas las cookies de ese sitio aun asi no funciona. tampoco en opera.

Comment: Básicamente estarías infringiendo la ley. te sugiero investigar la ley para el tratamiento de las cookies, hay muchos artículos en internet que hablan sobre esto

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, si, he leido un poco sobre la ley pero habrá algún problema de pronto en que algunos navegadores la bloqueen o algo así?

Comment: No soy un experto en leyes, pero creo que las cookies que son parte necesaria de tu aplicación (para recordar al usuario y su sesión, o para ajustar la experiencia del usuario incluso aunque no esté identificado) no tienes por qué declararlas. Las cookies de las que tienes que avisar son las que se usan para monitorizar la navegación, las cookies de terceros usadas para colocar publicidad... etc. Por ejemplo, Google adwords, google analytics, facebook... Una cookie para un token CSRF es algo que forma parte de la seguridad de la aplicación. Más información aquí: https://gdpr.eu/cookies/

Comment: gracias @PabloLozano por tu respuesta, lo que pasa es que estoy teniendo inconvenientes con mi pagina porque algunos navegadores no están guardando el token en las cookies, por eso me preguntaba si era por el aviso o no se que está pasando.

Comment: @AndresMendez Te recomiendo que esa aclaración la pongas como parte de la pregunta, ya que tal y como está escrita es demasiado vaga y puede ser cerrada por demasiado amplia o por estar fuera de tema (si se entiende que preguntas más por el aspecto legal que por el aspecto técnico)

Comment: Esto depende del pais donde esta ubicada la pagina, no?